# Full screen background image

Tags: android

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/bg"
>
```

My bg.png is nothing special so it can be stretched. In the preview in eclipse I can see the background. On my device there is no background set though.

What did I do wrong ?

---

I cleaned it but it didn't do anything. Still no background. The only thing I can think of is how I reset some layouts in my code to make them fit perfectly in every screen size. The main layout where i set the background is not touched in the code though !

Edit: That's not the problem either. I commented it out and still no bg

---

Okay i just tested something and it worked. Oviously Android isn't able to shrink pictures. My bg.png had a size of 1600x2500 and nothing was displayed (I tried it on the Galaxy S4 with a resolution of 1080x1920).  So I changed the size of the picture to 500x800 and it's been displayed.

Comment: Here, nothing wrong I can see...clean your project then run it again...may be that can help you.

Comment: What do you mean ? How to clean my project ?

Comment: Do you have other nested elements (with backgrounds of their own) in your linear layout?

Comment: Yes I do. I have several buttons with their background images

Comment: please post a screenshot of your screen..so that we can see what's wrong